# angular/cli is not running on my linux mint OS

Tags: angular, angular-cli

my configuration -

node ->  v8.4.0

npm  ->  v5.6.0

after running command-

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

(after migrating into desired folder)when i ran -

```
ng new ng-app1
```

this is what i got -

[image]

can anyone explain what i did wrong !!

Comment: mmm looks like ng cli is not installed well ..try to reinstall it maybe with npm install -g @angular/cli --force

Comment: i tried, but still getting the same error

Comment: Did you try `sudo ng new ng-app1`?

Comment: yes, i did try the command as sudo